# What is the proper usage of Python logging in structured program?

Tags: python, logging

I have such case. I have a program with main file which imports some class from module. Like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
from common.external import External


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Fetches the externals by given XML file or HTTP(S)/SVN URL containting it.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'xml', nargs=1,
        help='XML file or URL',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-p', '--path', dest='path',
        help='Path to fetch externals (default: .)',
        default='.'
    )
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    extcfg = External(options.xml, options.path)
    extcfg.update_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like add logging to both main program and some methods of the class. How should properly do that ? Should make two different logger for each module I use ? Shall I pass the logger object to the class ? How to code it to possibly seperate program logic from logging. Ideas ?

I researched the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial)
and [cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html). But it doesn't give me any concluding answers.